# How to save and average two values associated with radio buttons?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a student working on developing an application to calculate a skiers chance of getting injured. The application requires users to enter their own variables such as ability and equipment. I am having trouble assigning and saving a value to each of the different radio buttons. For example I can click on the "hat" button which will change the Percent value to "67" but this value will not have any effect on when I click on another radio button. Is there any chance you can help with creating code that will average the values of the two radio buttons?

HTML:

```
<h1>Personal Information</h1>

<h2>Gear</h2>
<input type="radio" onclick="changeText(.7)" name="group2"/> Helmet
<input type="radio" onClick="changeText(.67)" name="group2"/> Hat

<h2>Ability</h2>
<input type="radio" onclick="changeText(.7)" name="group2"/> Beginner
<input type="radio" onclick="changeText(.7)" name="group2"/> Intermediate
<input type="radio" onclick="changeText(.7)" name="group2"/> Advanced

<h2>Risk</h2>    
Precent % <input type="text" id="count" value="1%"/>
```

Javascript:

```
function changeText(value) {
     document.getElementById('count').value = 1 * value;   
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/J7m7m/339/

Comment: It'd be good to post your javascript `changeText` function in the question. Use the link at the bottom of your question to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28617606/edit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed your javascript to the following. It may not work exactly how you'd like. Currently it continues to average all values passed `changeText`.

For example, if you select "Hat" and keep on changing your mind on whether you're a beginner of intermediate, the average keeps moving closer to 0.7 since it starts off averaging just `{0.67, 0.7}` but then starts averaging `{0.67, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, ... }` the more times you click around.

```
var aggregate = 0;
var times = 0;

function changeText(value) {
    aggregate += value;
    times++;

    if (times == 0)
    {
        document.getElementById('count').value = 1 * value;
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('count').value = aggregate / times;   
    }
}
```

The basic key point is that you'll need to keep track of what was passed to you.

You could change it, for example, to just store the previous value instead of accumulating an aggregate and always divide by 2 to just get the average of the last two values.

```
var previousValue = null;

function changeText(value) {
    if (!previousValue)
        document.getElementById('count').value = 1 * value;
    else
        document.getElementById('count').value = (previousValue + value) / 2;   

    previousValue = value;
}
```

Depending on what you want, you may need to write two functions, one to report the value associated with the level and one associated with the equipment (maybe call them `ReportGearRisk()` and `ReportAbilityRisk()`). Each one could store the value provided into separate fields (maybe `gearRisk` and `abilityRisk`) and call another function (maybe `UpdateUI()`) that would check those fields and decide how to update the UI.